# How can I generate multiple public classes for one class file in java using java agent

Tags: java, classloader, javaagents

I'm generating bytecode for two public classes based on one input classfile in java using java agent.

Now I've already got two byte arrays with the byte code of generated classes in them at the transform function in a subclass of ClassFileTransformer. How can I directly load them into JVM without saving them to disk files?

Code looks like this

```java
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class classBeingRedefined, 
    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer)
throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    byte[] classOne = generateEhancedClass(className, classFileBuffer, loader);
    byte[] classTwo = generateShadowClass(className, classFileBuffer,loader);

    // TODO load both classOne and classTwo into loader

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without tricks. As you have the `ClassLoader` available, you can call the `defineClass` method directly. This does however require reflection and is no longer possible in Java 9 without explicitly exporting the `java.lang` package.